# Cannot access folder on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, php

I'm trying to open a PHP file on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. But it won't let me move the file from its current location to the 'www' folder I keep getting an error message saying 'Access Denied', I've looked online and it seems that I need to login with the credentials 'pi' and 'raspberry' however I never logged in before, I was always automatically logged in when I turned the Pi on. Is there any way to get over this issue? I'm sure it's simple but I'm not used to Raspberry Pi's so it's difficult

Answer (score 1):

You are logged in automatically as the Pi user with the default password. The reaason you can't copy a file to the /var/www/ directory is because you do not own the folder. To get around this do the following from a termianl window:

switch to the directory where the file you want to move is located (assuming the file is in your home directory):

```
cd
```

then move the file with the following command (substituing the file name you want to move):

```
sudo mv name_of_file_to_move /var/www/
```

If you want to copy the file instead of moving it use this command instead of the previous one:

```
sudo cp name_of_file_to_copy /var/www/
```

When asked for a password use raspberry (assuming you have not changed the password).

you can check the file has been moved to the new location with the following command:

```
ls -la /var/www/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this command in the terminal  to make your user the owner: 'chown user /path/to/your/directory' make sure only folder for now not the file for the file use 'chown user /path/to/your//folders/file/you/need/access/'

**above just replace the 'user' with your account thats not the root account the one that you are signed into for file browsing!**


and replace the '/path/to/your/directory'  and '/path/to/your//folders/file/you/need/access/' to your exact file path
Also you can use a /* to gain access to all files and supfoldors in a directory

Answer (score -1):

Use `sudo raspi-config` to run the initial config again and setup a new root user so you can use it to have the priviliges you need.

[Reference](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md)

Comment: This is not required. His Pi is setup to autologin as the Pi user. The issue is that the Pi user does not own the www directory, and as a result he needs to use sudo to move the file.